# Js active link not working in cakephp

Tags: javascript, jquery, cakephp

I am trying to apply active link in cakephp by js.Here after click on link it is working until loading page.After loaded the page js active is not working here.I have tried below code.

```
 <div class="list-group">
    <a class="list-group-item"  onclick="return false" style="background:#428BCA;color:#fff;border-color: #428BCA;">Actions</a>
    <?php echo $this->Html->link(__('Add New User'), array('controller' => 'users','action' => 'add'),array('class'=>'list-group-item')); ?>    
    <?php echo $this->Html->link(__('Add New Subject'), array('controller' => 'subjects','action' => 'add'),array('class'=>'list-group-item')); ?>
    <?php echo $this->Html->link(__('Add New Post'), array('controller' => 'posts','action' => 'add'),array('class'=>'list-group-item')); ?>
    <?php echo $this->Html->link(__('Add New Video'), array('controller' => 'videos','action' => 'add'),array('class'=>'list-group-item')); ?>
</div>
```

here is my js code

```
<script>
         $(document).ready(function(e){
         $('.list-group a').click(function(e){
         $('.list-group a.active').removeClass("active");
         $(this).addClass("active");
         return true;
         });
        });
</script>
```

Have there any solution to solve this problem ?

Comment: how does the output of the php look like? And can you provide an jsFiddle of your problem with the generated html?

Comment: Here active state is working until page loading.After complete load the page active is not working.Sorry I don't know how to add cakephp code in jsFiddle. www.bdschool24.com Here I have tried in sidebar link.

Comment: I've tried your sidebar in Chrome and works like it should (for as far I can say). While clicking it turns blue.

Comment: What is the solution now?

Comment: what browser are you using?

Comment: Mozilla firefox.I also tried it by chrome too.Same result like Mozilla.

Comment: Works the same for me. I'm not quite sure anymore what the problem is. Maybe you can provide a small example in jsFiddle in plain html, css and js.

Comment: There is no CakePHP in this question since `Html->link` just outputs a `<a>link</a>`tag. If you replace the view code with the rendered html it should make your question clearer - and also make it more obvious how you _can_ use jsFiddle.